# update website automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to ckeditor.  Please need some help.  Say for example, I have posted my web page on godaddy server and I want to make some change on text for eg: `index.html` page.

So, when I make some changes and click on save button of ckeditor tool.  Will that web page posted on godaddy server will be automatically updated?  When I reopen or refresh that page posted on godaddy will those changes show?

Will I need to publish that page?

In tools like wordpress and vignette, you make changes and click on publish and it automatically makes changes to the website. So, in same way can it be done in ckeditor?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is godaddy. You should think about switching hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Ckeditor wont magically update static pages.  Ckeditor is a tool for modifying textarea input.